# Getting index of one array elements in another array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get the index of one array elements in another array using LINQ
The following are my two array:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "Albany", "Albuquerque", "Anchorage", "Atlantic City",
           "Baton Rouge", "Biloxi", "CEDAR SPRINGS", "Chicago", "Columbia", "Columbus" };
string[] arr2 = new string[] { "Albany", "Biloxi" };
```

Can anybody help me out on the same?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This site helps solving issues with your code. You should **post your code** here when you have results which are different from expected, or when you get an error. You also should describe **what results you have and what is expected** and/or provide error details. After that community will help you to solve issues and (sometimes) it'll give you some guidance. That is how stackoverflow works. As you can see, your question doesn't have all appropriate information. Please **edit** your question and add code with other required information if you want to get some help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int[] indicesOf2In1 = arr2.Select(s => Array.IndexOf(arr1, s)).ToArray(); // (0,5)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! that was really helpfull

Comment: @sindhoo: you're welcome. Remember to accept the answer.